# Wifi not responding on Lenovo Z710

Tags: wireless

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my new Lenovo Z710. It connects with the wifi but mozilla does not show the home page (google.com).
Kindly suggest a solution.

warm regards,
Amit.

Comment: Try opening a terminal and run `ping google.com`. If you do get data being transfered then you do have an internet connection systemwide.

Comment: Reposted from an answer by user1738234: *The situation is that everything is working (I can surf with the cable )...the laptop can connect to the wireless...but there is no internet. So I checked the wifi router...DLink ...and the problem seems to be there. When I connect my laptop with the wifi hotspot from my samsung S3, it responds....but not normally.*

Answer (score 1):

Go to the link below and set the home page

http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/How%20to%20set%20the%20home%20page